# ReactTooltip - react-tooltip anchor is not showing up

Tags: reactjs, tooltip, react-tooltip

ReactTooltip anchor is not showing up when I'm hovering on the element. The tooltip is visible but the anchor is not getting displayed.

I'm using a previous version of ReactTooltip - 4.2.21

```
import "./ProgressChartTooltip.scss";
import ReactTooltip from "react-tooltip";
import TextDisplay from "../../../../../../chat/TextDisplay/TextDisplay";
import coin from "../../../../../../../assets/icons/coin.svg";

export function ProgressChartTooltip() {
  return (
    <div>
      <div data-tip data-for="preview">
        ◕
      </div>
      <ReactTooltip
        id="preview"
        place="top"
        effect="float"
        backgroundColor="#D8D8DF"
        className="stTooltip"
      >
        {/* question preview */}
        <div className="quesPreview">
          <TextDisplay text="Laborum in ipsum veniam et voluptate eiusmod irure ut voluptate velit officia. Ex aute elit commodo exercitation consectetur ad. Proident laboris ad dolor laborum." />
        </div>
        {/* unit info */}
        <div className="unitInfo">
          <div className="unitTitle">
            Expressions, Equations, and Inequalities
          </div>
          <div className="unitDesc">
            Solve area and perimeter problems (algebraic)
          </div>
          <div className="unitProgress">
            {/* unit completion progress */}
            {/* Attempted or not - progress chart icon */}
            <div>0/4 complete | Not tried</div>
          </div>
        </div>
        {/* display coins */}
        <button className="coinButton">
          <img src={coin} alt="coin-icon" className="coinIcon" />
          <span className="coins">400</span>
        </button>
      </ReactTooltip>
    </div>
  );
}
```

This is how I want :
[image]

And this is how it is getting displayed. NO ANCHOR TIP:
[image]

How can I get the ANCHOR tip displayed????